# how to set sonarqube in terraform using docker image and postgres DB in azure

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube, terraform

In terraform tf file using linux_fx_version to install sonarqube docker image as below

```
site_config { 
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|(sonarqube:latest)" 
    always_on        = "true" 
  }
```

the full main.tf is below:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
}

module "postgresql_server" {
  source = "../modules/postgresql_server"

  resource_group_name           = "${module.resource_group.name}"
  resource_group_location       = "${module.resource_group.location}"
  postgresql_server_name        = "sonar-postgresql-server"
  postgresql_server_admin_login = "${var.sonar_postgresql_admin_login}"
  postgresql_server_admin_password = "${var.sonar_postgresql_admin_password}"
  keyvault_id = "${module.keyvault.id}"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_database" "sonar_db" {
  name                = "${var.sonar_db_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${module.resource_group.name}"
  server_name         = "${module.postgresql_server.name}"
  charset             = "UTF8"
  collation           = "English_United States.1252"
}

# Create a new Resource Group 
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "sonargroup" { 
  name     = "sonar-webapp-containers" 
  location = "${var.resource_group_location}" 
} 


# Create an App Service Plan with Linux 
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" { 
  name                = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.name}-plan" 
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.location}" 
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.name}" 


  # Define Linux as Host OS 
  kind = "Linux" 


  # Choose size 
  sku { 
    tier = "Standard" 
    size = "S1" 
  } 


  properties { 
    reserved = true # Mandatory for Linux plans 
  } 
 } 


 # Create an Azure Web App for Containers in that App Service Plan 
 resource "azurerm_app_service" "dockerapp" { 
  name                = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.name}-dockerapp" 
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.location}" 
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.group.name}" 
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id}" 


  # Do not attach Storage by default 
  app_settings { 
    WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE = false 

    /* 
    # Settings for private Container Registires   
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = "" 
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = "" 
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "" 
    */ 
  } 


  # Configure Docker Image to load on start 
  site_config { 
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|(sonarqube:latest)" 
    always_on        = "true" 
  } 


  identity { 
    type = "SystemAssigned" 
  } 
}
```

I have mentioned azure postgres db and sonar docker image in main.tf
how can i mention sonarqube to use the declared postgres db in terraform? how do i bridge the postgres db and sonarqube (docker image) in terraform

trying to replicate the below in terraform

```
docker network create mynet 

docker run --name sonar-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=sonar -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar -d -p 5432:5432 --net mynet postgres 

docker run --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://sonar-postgres:5432/sonar -d --net mynet sonarqube:latest
```

Comment: Hi Ani, are you able to share if this was successful and what the other files looked like? I am trying to do the same and having some issues replicating the ability to set sonarqube  in terraform with a docker image

Answer (score 0):

can you give the details on what setting will you use to start the docker container.

You can take a look of `app_command_line`, it will help.

```
site_config supports the following:

app_command_line - (Optional) App command line to launch, e.g. /sbin/myserver -b 0.0.0.0.
```

reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#app_command_line

Comment: trying to replicate the below in terraform docker network create mynet
docker run --name sonar-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=sonar -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar -d -p 5432:5432 --net mynet postgres
docker run --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://sonar-postgres:5432/sonar -d --net mynet sonarqube:latest

Answer (score 0):

Mention below in app_settings, fixed the issue

```
SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME = "${var.sonar_postgresql_admin_login}@${module.postgresql_server.name}"
SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD = "${var.sonar_postgresql_admin_password}"
SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://${module.postgresql_server.name}.postgres.data
```